# Migrating .NET Framework to .NET Core 6 RequestBase

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a an MVC .NET Framework 4.7.2 that I am migrating to .NET 6. The .NET Framework had a NuGet package library that was built in house (company I work for) and expected HttpRequestBase as a parameter. How would I pass in a parameter from .NET 6 to this library?

So far I am thinking that this NuGet Package will have to be upgrade to expect a parameter of
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest ?

Comment: What does this NuGet package do with RequestBase?

Comment: I went to the implementation and it gets querystrings from the Request.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6 and has no HttpRequestBase. None of the web stacks (Web API, MVC, Razor pages) use it. In .NET Core the base HTTP class is [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0). You can't use this package. You'll have to rewrite the code, assuming it's even needed. ASP.NET Core middleware removes the need for a *lot* of ASP.NET Old extensions

Comment: What does this package do? You can't use it, but you may be able to create the same functionality as a middleware. Or the features may already be available out of the box

Comment: Its a package that generates reports, ssrs/excel/pdf and sends emails and gets the request to extract querystrings/parameters. I am going to get a list of methods it uses and see if I can add them to my program and bypass this package.

Comment: This might be of use https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/incremental-asp-net-to-asp-net-core-migration/

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, I suggest you use [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

For example, getting query string in ASP.NET Core MVC:

```cs
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public void Index(string name)
    {            
        var data = HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution comes from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P96l0pDNVpM or you can read the article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/incremental-asp-net-to-asp-net-core-migration/

1. I did a test and converted my .NET Framework library to .NET Standard and added package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters.
2. I compiled and took the DLLs to the .NET Core Web project and was able to call the method that was expecting the paramater **HttpRequestBase request**
3. My .NET Core Web project did have package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters to work with converting the old project (.NET Framework MVC)